# What is logcheck, and why is it consuming 100% CPU out of the blue?

Tags: services

I have a server that's hardly used, basically a fresh linode VPS with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

It has been running for 14 months with hardly a blip in the CPU graphs (2% max, average over 2 hours). Suddenly, the past 2 hours have been at 100%.

The culprit is an `egrep` running by the user `logcheck`. Most references I find to this question on google are from many years ago (2005, 2007, 2010).

Any suggestions? Killing the process just spawns another one.

I'm not sure what this is: all the docs I find point to gentoo where it appears to be a log filtering program for sending data to sysadmins. If this isn't something that is scheduled by default with `ubuntu`, I'm not sure why it's running at this particular moment.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have the exact command line of the offending `egrep` process?  That would help determine whether egrep is suddenly looking at a lot more files than usual, or a lot bigger files than usual, etc.

Comment: Had the same problem in my Kubuntu-install; Logcheck/egrep using up 50% of my dualcore-CPU. Uninstalled Logcheck via Apper and killed running processes.

Answer (score 3):

logcheck basically scans your system log files and then emails suspecious issues usually to root.  If I recall the program runs via cron....that means it might be hiding in a few different places: (1) in standard root crontab entry, (2) in /etc/crontab, (3) as an entry under /etc/cron.d, or (4) under one of the "run-parts" subdirectories like /etc/cron.daily.

Depending on how big your log files are it can take the programming a bit of time to go through and examine this information, summarize it and then email it.

Comment: thank you! I found it in `/etc/cron.d/logcheck`. It sounds like something installed in all my other systems too, except it doesn't choke this badly. I'll try to figure out why this particular system spends many hours..

Comment: it has been running for multiple days, even when I kill the process, and delete the temporary files. Any suggestions on how to debug this? Much appreciated sir!

Comment: @YujiTomita At the risk of coming across as rude - if you don't know how to do basic debugging of a runaway process, you should either contact a sysadmin within your company to ask for help, or hire a consultant. Or, at the very least, your boss should pay for the training necessary for you to work as a sysadmin in addition to your development duties.

Comment: @JennyD, does server fault have a policy on low level questions? I do applaud your community for policing itself and will try my best to not ask stupid questions.

Comment: @YujiTomita Yes - the policy is that it's a question about how to manage systems in a professional capacity. A professional sysadmin should know how to debug this. It's not a stupid question, it's just one that's not on-topic at ServerFault. I will vote to transfer it to [unix.se] instead which doesn't have that restriction - I was out of votes yesterday so I couldn't do it then.

Comment: Also, I really meant it that your boss should let you get the training to do sysadmin work. It's really not fair to you to put you in a situation to manage servers and not give you access to the tools you need. I would certainly not be a good web designer because that's not what I'm trained in and my being a good sysadmin wouldn't help there. This is the same situation, just from the other side.